Invert a power series (by Lagrange inversion theorem)
Expand the function $z = g(w)$ in a power series of $w$ if
$$
    w = \frac{e^z - 1}{e^{a z}}, \qquad a \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}, \quad g(0) = 0.
$$
Find the radius $R$ of convergence of the obtained power series.
This task has the Answer:
$$
    g(w) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{C_{an}^n}{an} w^n, \qquad R = \frac{(a-1)^{a-1}}{a^a}.
$$
Solution attempt.
It is clear that $f(z) = \frac{e^z - 1}{e^{a z}}$, $g(w)=f^{-1}(w)$, $z_0=w_0=0$ and we must use Lagrange inversion theorem or its modifications.
Then $g(w) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n w^n$, where
$$
  n!c_n
  =
  \lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( \frac{z-z_0}{f(z)-w_0}\right)^n
  =
  \lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( \frac{z}{f(z)}\right)^n
  =
  \lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left(\frac{ze^{a z}}{e^z-1}\right)^n.
$$
How to find the (n-1)-th derivative of $\left(\frac{ze^{a z}}{e^z-1}\right)^n$? (Why $c_n=\frac{C_{an}^n}{an}$?)
It is unclear how to obtain the answer even by general Leibniz rule.
Moreover, it is unclear how to obtain $R$ using the Cauchy-Hadamard formula even knowing $c_n$ from the answer.

Which step precisely is unclear to you in this answer? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-explanation: "For posts seeking explanation or clarification of a specific step in a proof. "Please explain this proof" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof requires explanation, and why so."

There is a slightly different expansion using a variant of the theorem. Also see Norlund polynomials which may possibly help

Thanks, already thought of variant of Lagrange inversion theorem with composition...

As this  question has  been tagged complex  analysis we
present a complex variable proof by way of enrichment.
We seek
$$[w^n] g(w) = \frac{1}{n} [w^{n-1}] g'(w).$$
This is
$$\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^n} g'(w) \; dw.$$
Now put $w=(\exp(z)-1)/\exp(az)$ to get
$$\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{\exp(anz)}{(\exp(z)-1)^n} \; dz.$$
Next introduce $v=\exp(z)$ to obtain
$$\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|v-1|=\rho}
\frac{v^{an-1}}{(v-1)^n} \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|v-1|=\rho}
\frac{1}{(v-1)^n}
\sum_{q=0}^{an-1} {an-1\choose q} (v-1)^q \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{n} {an-1\choose n-1}
= \frac{1}{an} {an\choose n}.$$
This is the first part of the task. With the second part
for the ratio between consecutive terms we find
$$\frac{an+a}{an} \frac{(an)!}{n! \times (an-n)!}
\frac{(n+1)! \times (an+a-n-1)!}{(an+a)!}.$$
Now we have
$$\frac{(an)!}{(an+a)!} = \prod_{q=1}^a \frac{1}{an+q}
= \frac{1}{(an)^a} \prod_{q=1}^a \frac{1}{1+q/a/n}
\\ = \frac{1}{(an)^a} 
\exp\left[\sum_{q=1}^a \log \frac{1}{1+q/a/n} \right].$$
With $n$  large we may  replace the logarithm  with the
first term of its Taylor series to get
$$\frac{1}{(an)^a} 
\exp\left[- \frac{1}{an} \sum_{q=1}^a q \right]
= \frac{1}{(an)^a} 
\exp\left[- \frac{1}{2} \frac{a+1}{n}\right].$$
We also have
$$\frac{(an+a-n-1)!}{(an-n)!}
= \prod_{q=1}^{a-1} (an-n+q)
= (an-n)^{a-1} \prod_{q=1}^{a-1} (1+q/(a-1)/n)
\\ = (an-n)^{a-1} 
\exp\left[ \sum_{q=1}^{a-1} \log (1+q/(a-1)/n) \right]
\sim (an-n)^{a-1} 
\exp\left[\frac{1}{(a-1)n} \sum_{q=1}^{a-1} q \right]
= (an-n)^{a-1} 
\exp\left[\frac{1}{2} \frac{a}{n} \right].$$
Collecting everything,
$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{n}
n^{a-1} (a-1)^{a-1} \frac{1}{n^a a^a}
\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2n}\right]
\\ = \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}
\frac{(a-1)^{a-1}}{a^a} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2n}\right]
\sim \frac{(a-1)^{a-1}}{a^a}.$$
This will do  it for the radius of  convergence.
Remark on  the contours. We have  $z=w+\cdots$ from
the  problem  statement  and  the  functional  equation
(computing $c_1$  by substitution)  so we  may actually
take $\varepsilon=\gamma.$ We  also have $v=1+z+\cdots$
so   we   may  take   $\rho=\varepsilon=\gamma.$   Here
$\gamma\lt  (a-1)^{a-1}/a^a \lt  1  \lt  2\pi.$ With  a
non-zero radius  of convergence  this series  about the
origin  represents an  analytic function  $g(w)$ there,
which justifies  the initial application of  the CCF to
$g'(w).$ Supposing analyticity in a neighborhood of the
origin  we have  obtained just  such a  branch and  the
corresponding radius of convergence.

Marko Riedel, thank you a lot. You have given a very interesting solution.
Concerning your remark about contours, I will add that we can also reasoning in the following way. Since $f'(0)\ne0$, there exists a neighborhood in which $f'(z)\ne0$, hence $f$ is locally univalent and its inverse function is also holomorphic and locally univalent in some neighborhood of the point $w=0$.

This task is taken from the topic about local inversion of holomorphic function by means of Lagrange inversion theorem.
So the only strange thing is that it is very difficult to find the $(n-1)$-th derivative of $\left(\frac{ze^{a z}}{e^z-1}\right)^n$ at the point $z=0$.

Re. the edit with $\gamma\lt 2\pi$, the function in $z$ has a pole there.

It turns out that $\gamma<1<2\pi$. What is the purpose of the second inequality?

Notice that we took $\varepsilon=\gamma$. We don't want to hit the pole at $z=2\pi i.$

I dont understand: f(z) dosn't have any poles in $\mathbb C$. But $g(w)$ has isolated second-order branch points $w^=\frac{(a-1)^{a-1}}{a^a}e^{2a\pi ki}$ and $g'(w)$ has the poles in $w^$, as $f'(z^)=0$, where $w^=f(z^*)$.

Well $\exp(anz)/(\exp(z)-1)$ has closest poles at $\pm 2\pi i.$ So we don't want these inside our contour $|z|=\varepsilon.$
